# Assertion Error while using LinearRegression

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, linear-regression

I was trying to help a friend who is trying to use `LinearRegression` in a signal. Data contains 20,000 records and just two columns (time and pulse) and I'm running it in Databricks' Community. My approach is pretty simple and biased I know, I tried to add more artificial features, for this I created this simple and yet useful function.

```
def featuresCreator(x, grad, acc):
  if (grad > 0):
    return [x ** grad]
  else:
    return [x ** grad] + featuresCreator(x, grad - acc, acc)

featuresUDF = udf(lambda x, grad, acc: DenseVector(featuresCreator(x, grad, acc)), VectorUDT())
```

I thought that powering the feature several times and within a range of values would help me to *overfit* the regression, this is the reason why I ran this.

```
xf = df.select(featuresUDF(col("tiempo"), lit(12), lit(0.1)).alias("features"), col(" pulso").alias("label"))
```

Everything was fine the `DataFrame` had only 2 columns, one of features and the other for the label. The problem comes later when I try to use `LinearRegression` over the data.

```
lr = LinearRegression().setFeaturesCol("features").setLabelCol("label").setMaxIter(200)
lrm = lr.fit(xf)
```

Here the program explodes and shows the following exception.

> java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: lapack.dppsv returned 5.

Is there any way to solve this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This errors typically mean that you passed a matrix which is not solvable.

Comment: So it's not related to the length of the vector?

Comment: No. Check INFO codes: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d62/dppsv_8f.html: _the leading minor of order i of A is not
                positive definite, so the factorization could not be
                completed, and the solution has not been computed_

Comment: @zero323 I think that's your comments create a valid answer !

Comment: @zero323 should I close the question? I think this information might be of some help for someone else. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think it should be close @AlbertoBonsanto I've even up voted it and that's rare ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This errors typically mean that you passed a matrix which is not solvable.

So actually it's not related to the length of the vector

> Check INFO codes: netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d62/dppsv_8f.html: the leading minor of order i of A is not positive definite, so the factorization could not be completed, and the solution has not been computed

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved using solver parameter for Linear Regression.

```
val lf=new LinearRegression().setSolver("l-bfgs")
```

by default it is normal.